# db.collections.updateOne(filter,update,options) not working with $pull operator

Tags: mongodb

I am just running a db.collections.updateOne() query on mongo shell with $pull operator. It works as expected with $set operator but doesn't affect the document with $pull. Am I missing something here? 
    Thanks

I found an answer to the same problem someone else posted here [How to remove embedded scheme document in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170520/how-to-remove-embedded-scheme-document-in-mongoose)

I dont seem to see where I am going wrong with this

```
db.vendors.findOne({"_id":ObjectId("5da0343c724f9d0531eeaa4a")})
```

This is the document I need to update:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da0343c724f9d0531eeaa4a"),
    "elements" : [
        ObjectId("5da03451724f9d0531eeaa4b")
    ],
    "packages" : [ ],
    "title" : "test again",
    "slug" : "celebration-company",
    "__v" : 1,
    "department" : ObjectId("5d9892b1c46b6306b2ce64aa")
}
```

Here is what I am running on the shell:

```
db.vendors.updateOne({"_id":ObjectId("5da0343c724f9d0531eeaa4a")},
{$pull:
    {"elements":
           {"_id":ObjectId("5da03451724f9d0531eeaa4b")}
     }
  })
```

Result:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Comment: Does the `elements` array contain any elements with a key of "_id"?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I had used Data Association by embedding elements documents into vendor documents. One vendor can have many elements. So _id is the mongoose object id of the elements documents embedded inside of the vendor documents.

Comment: You example document doesn't show any `_id` - it only shows the ObjectId without any key, which could be the issue with your query.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I see your point now. I used data association by reference. So I could only see the ObjectIds and not the whole document. I assumed that _id will work like this but it doesnt. 

So after reading your comment, I first populated the elements document and then the pull option worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!